# how to pass argument (slug) for `success_url` in Django `DeleteView`

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I am using `DeleteView` to delete posts from a forum group. I would like to define `success_url` in a way so the user will be redirected to the post list within the same group where the deleted post was. The issue is that I don't know how to pass the group name (slug) from `confirm_delete.html` page to `DeleteView` in `views.py`.

```py
# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('delete/<slug>/<pk>/', views.DeleteMyPost.as_view(), name='delete')
]
```

```
# views.py
class DeleteMyPost(DeleteView):
    model = models.MyPost

    def get_success_url(self,*args,**kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy(
            'desired_url_name',
             kwargs={'slug':self.kwargs.get('slug')}
        )
```

```py
# mypost_confirm_delete.html
<form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
```

It doesn't work right now as slug is not being passed to `DeleteView`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

views:

```
class DeleteMyPost(DeleteView):

model = models.MyPost

def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return reverse_lazy('desired_url_name', args=[self.kwargs['slug']])
```

In your list template put a link to the delete template like:

```
<a href="{% url 'mypost_confirm_delete' slug=slug pk=mypost.id %}">Delete</a>
```

Good luck!